# Error importing storage module staticfiles.storage: "No module named staticfiles.storage"

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm trying to start barebone site with django-cms 2.2 and django 1.2.3, but receive this error:

```
 Error importing storage module staticfiles.storage: "No module named staticfiles.storage"
```

when going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin.
What one needs to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django cms 2.2 says you need django 1.2.5 or django 1.3.

I'd definitely grab django 1.3.

You'll have to add a few settings related to the new `staticfiles` app but once it's running you should be good to go. It seems django-cms moved their static files to work with the new staticfiles system.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/